# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on TCP

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, httpclient, google-compute-engine

So recently I have migrated my services (written in Java) to GCP from AWS. One of my service interacts with other service (both in GCP) through HTTP (java HttpClient). A very weird behaviour is happening where I am randomly getting **java.net.SocketException: Connection reset** like :-

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>       at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_151]

This thing never happened in AWS but is happening in GCP with the same code. To me it seems that something is off about the machine configuration. I have tried changing the machines with no luck. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong here possibly?

Comment: perhaps you should check java jdk versions ?

Comment: java jdk versions are same in GCP and AWS

Comment: Where are this service deployed? In an instance in GCE? Or in App Engine?

Comment: Both services are now running in GCE. Earlier they were in AWS

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a firewall rule to accept the [incoming traffic from one instance to the other?](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules)

Comment: Yes, firewall rules are in place. Has this been the firewall issue, every http request would have produced the error. But as I mentioned in my question, java.net.SocketException, is happening randomly for some requests and not all.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you tell how you resolved this issue ?